# NameError: name 'Class' is not defined (Python)

Tags: python, nameerror, defined

So I'm trying to make Save and Load files for a text based game...
Saving works, and overwrites the save if you save again.
But loading brings up the NameError.

```
def save():
    my_file = open("save.txt", "w")
    my_file.write(Class + "\n")
    my_file.write(level + "\n") 
    my_file.write(str(hp) + "\n")
    my_file.write(str(atk) + "\n")
    my_file.write(str(Def) + "\n")
    my_file.write(str(spd)+ "\n")
    my_file.write(str(ene)+ "\n")
    my_file.write(str(race1)+ "\n")
    my_file.close()

def load():
    infile = open("save.txt")

    lines = infile.readlines()

    line_number = 0

    while line_number < len(lines):

        Class = lines[line_number]
        level = lines[line_number + 1]
        hp = lines[line_number + 2]
        atk = lines[line_number + 3]
        Def = lines[line_number + 4]
        spd = lines[line_number + 5]
        ene = lines[line_number + 6]
        race1 = lines[line_number + 7]

        line_number += 8
        print(Class, level, hp, atk, Def, spd, ene, race1)


    infile.close()
    identify()
```

Above is the save and load definitions..

Here is the Class input definition:

```
def class_level():
        global Class
        global level
        Class = input("Please input your class: ")
        print()
        level = input("Please input your level: ")
        print()
        race()
```

And here is the indentify definition:

```
def identify():
    global hp
    global atk
    global Def
    global spd
    global ene
    if re.match(r"warrior", Class, re.I):  <---- This is the line the error is on, Class not defined
    print()
```

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong? It will load the file and display it.. but then say that Class is not defined in the def identify.
Thanks.

Comment: Who calls class_level and load? Are those in the same module? Globals are only global relative to the current module!

Answer (score 0):

In python the way global works is that it does not only define a variable as a global variable. It adds the variable to the local namespace from the global namespace if present. If it is not present, it creates a global instance and adds that to the local namepsace. You might have `Class` as a variable in global namespace, but inside your `identify` function local namespace, `Class` is not present. You will need to add `Class` to the local namespace of `identify`. You do that by adding the line `global Class`. Now the local namespace has a reference to the the variable `Class`

```
def identify():
    global hp
    global atk
    global Def
    global spd
    global ene
    # You need to mention global Class as well
    global Class
    if re.match(r"warrior", Class, re.I): 
    print()
```